# How can I point to EditText elements that are generated dynamically in a ListView in Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-edittext, android-listfragment

I am creating a ListView in a ListFragment and it is being populated dynamically, and I have no clue how many items are going to be there. Now I need the user to set the text of EditTexts for each item in the ListView in order to save this text by clicking one single button. My question is, how can I point to the EditText of each item when in fact I have only one EditText in the layout. My code just saves the first EditText text in the list. Does anyone have an idea? I am sorry! I am kind of new to Android.

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        // General ListView optimization code.
        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
            viewHolder.deviceName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        BluetoothDevice device = mLeDevices.get(i);
        viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());

        saveNode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < mLeDeviceListAdapter.getCount() ; j++) {
                    String name = viewHolder.deviceName.getText().toString();
                    String address = viewHolder.deviceAddress.getText().toString();
                    handler = new DataHandler(getActivity().getBaseContext());
                    handler.open();
                    handler.insertNode(address, name);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Node " + name + " inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    handler.close();
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to understand your question but cant seem to figure out what you are looking for.  Can you be more specific?  Are you adding EditTexts within the list item?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Eugene! I am actually having a listview where every list item has an EditText. Those list items are bluetooth devices that I scan for. Now I need the user to write a name of his choice for each device that shows up in the list and then click a single button "Save" to save all these names. But, how can I use the editText.getText() for every editText in the listview?! I am using an Adapter and I am just repeating the single editText in the layout, and the EditText id will just refer to the first element in the listView, not all of them!

Comment: Sorry its a bit late. I will have a look at it

Comment: I will post code when I wake up. I think I have an idea on what you are trying to accomplish. You want to get each name in the list view edittext. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That's it! I just don't know how to address these EditText multiples to get their data. Thanks a lot for replying! Immensely appreciated!

Comment: Hey,

I was capable of solving it by getting the child position! Would post the code later on since I am still working in the lab! Thanks anyways :)

Regards,
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually shouldn't have had the button onClick method in the getView() at all. It should be in the onCreate like here:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scan_activity, container, false);

    mHandler = new Handler();
    saveNode = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.save_node_button);

    saveNode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mLeDeviceListAdapter.getCount() ; j++) {

                int wantedPosition = j; // Whatever position you're looking for
                int firstPosition = mLeDeviceListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() - mLeDeviceListView.getHeaderViewsCount(); // This is the same as child #0
                int wantedChild = wantedPosition - firstPosition;
                // Say, first visible position is 8, you want position 10, wantedChild will now be 2
                // So that means your view is child #2 in the ViewGroup:
                if (wantedChild < 0 || wantedChild >= mLeDeviceListView.getChildCount()) {
                  //Log.w(TAG, "Unable to get view for desired position, because it's not being displayed on screen.");
                  return;
                }
                // Could also check if wantedPosition is between listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() and listView.getLastVisiblePosition() instead.
                View wantedView = mLeDeviceListView.getChildAt(wantedChild);

                nodeName = (EditText) wantedView.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
                nodeAddress = (TextView) wantedView.findViewById(R.id.device_address);

                name = nodeName.getText().toString();
                address = nodeAddress.getText().toString();

                handler = new DataHandler(getActivity().getBaseContext());
                handler.open();
                handler.insertNode(address, name);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Node " + name + " inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                handler.close();
             }
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

And the getView() function should look like this:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        // General ListView optimization code.
        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
            viewHolder.deviceName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        BluetoothDevice device = mLeDevices.get(i);
        viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());
        return view;
    }
```